# Bubble sorting max number of times?

Tags: math, bubble-sort

I am trying to create a function that sorts 100 random numbers using bubble sort. 
I think I might be doing something wrong, however.. Let me show you my code first:

```
#define MAXVALUE 100

void sortera_nummer(int slumptal[]){
int i,j,temp,k=0;


for(i=0;i<MAXVALUE;i++){
    for(j=MAXVALUE-1;j>i;j--){
        if(slumptal[j-1]>slumptal[j]){
            temp=slumptal[j-1];
            slumptal[j-1]=slumptal[j];
            slumptal[j]=temp;
            k++;
        }
    }
}
printf("K = %d",k);
}
```

The numbers all get sorted from lowest to highest, so the sorting works. But I'm getting K = an unexpectedly high number. (It's been everywhere between 2300 to 2700.)

So now I'm wondering - what should be the max number of times a properly working bubble sort could run with 100 elements? What's the equation for calculating it?

(This is my first post here, I'm sorry if I made any mistakes.)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this worst case, it take `n` iterations of `n/2` swaps for a bubble sort with an input of order `n`.

Comment: I'm not very good with maths, could you explain that a bit easier, please?

EDIT: I'm assuming n, in this case, = 100?

Comment: The worst case would be when your input array is in complete descending order. In that case, the last element would take n-1 iterations to bubble up. In that iteration, the next smallest element would have gone to the last position in the first swap of the previous loop. And it would repeat.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but. If n, in this case, = 100. Then n^2 = 10 000.
Meaning 2300'ish-2700'ish isn't such a bad result after all, am I right?

Comment: At each iteration, the next smallest needs one fewer swaps than the previous loop.  The math ends up being that your `n^2=10 000` should be `n(n-1)/2=4 900`.  So about half of that sounds about right.  Another way to check would be to try `n=50`, which should lead to 1/4th as many swaps.

Comment: Just move the `k++` outside the `if` and its final value will no longer depend on the actual numbers but give you the maximal number of swaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worst case scenario is if the input array is sorted in descending order. The first loop executes 99 times, the next 98, the next 97...... which equates to "sum(n) from n=99 to n=1" , which means the worst case is n(n+1)/2, in your case n=99 that's 4950.